# Start Fresh in Current Branch - Force Pull or Checkout from Remote

Tags: git

Lets say I'm checked out locally to a branch called 'dev'.

I want to start completely over so that I can create a new branch based on whatever is in the remote dev branch.

How do I get Git to force a pull or checkout and bring everything completely down form the remote branch and totally override and replace all or any files in my local so I can start fresh again.  I don't care about losing stuff at all, in fact I want everything lost locally.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I think would be to just delete the "dev" branch locally:

```
git branch -D dev
```

Then check it out from the repo again:

```
git checkout dev
```

That way whatever you have is 100% matched with what was in the remote. It might also be good to run a git fetch before checking out the branch again.

Comment: While this works just fine, it's actually more complicated than necessary an relies on the behaviour that checking out an existing remote branch automatically tracks that branch from the remote.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to just delete your local branch.

```
git checkout -b TEMP
git branch -D TheBranch
git fetch origin
git checkout TheBranch
git branch -D TEMP
```

Comment: weird, so I deleted my local branch, and git still knows I'm in a branch somehow at the command-line even though I deleted the .git folder?

Comment: had to restart webstorm, was hanging onto cache probably

Comment: @WeDoTDD you should **NEVER** delete the .git folder unless you want to lose **all versioning history ever**

Comment: Small amendment to @Vogel612 's advice, it's completely acceptable as long as your repo exists remotely in its entirety (say, on GitHub). Early on with GIT I definitely had a habit of just wiping my entire repo folder and cloning it down again.

Comment: Why does it matter if I delete my local .git folder if I am reckoning fresh.  I get the latest history from the remote and just start off again

Comment: Yea I have no qualms about deleting stuff when I don't care to retain it locally such as this specific time

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to run a single command:

```
git reset --hard origin/dev
```

this should work wonderfully after you fetched from your remote, which I assume is named origin here.
This works because a `git fetch` stores the remote's branch tip locally.